# Convert a .ogg blob into a google drive file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, blob

**Background**

I want to record students speaking and then upload their recordings automatically to Google drive.

**Current state of affairs**

I have client side code which can produce a blob containing `.ogg` recording.

```
var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
```

I can send the blob to a Google apps script standalone script in a `doPost()` request. In this case I'm using axios with a promise.

```
axios.post("https://script.google.com/macros/s/SOME_ID/exec", blob)
  .then((response)=>{
   console.log(response)
  }).catch(error =>{
   console.log(error)
  })
```

The blob arrives at the standalone script.

**The standalone Google apps script**

```
function doPost(e) {


  var params = JSON.stringify(e.parameters);
  createNewSoundFile(params)
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(params); 
}

function createNewSoundFile(blob){
  var title = 'Was created from a recording'
  var folderId = 'SOME_FOLDER_ID'
  var resource = {
    title: title,
    parents: [
      {
        "id": folderId, 
        "kind": "drive#fileLink"
      }
    ],
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.audio', 
  };
  try{

  var newfile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob).id

  } catch(e){
   // Send error to Google sheet
   // Exception: The mediaData parameter only supports blob types for uploads.

  }
}
```

**Problem**

The above apps script code says the blob is not a support media type.

**Question**

How can I create become a new `.ogg` file in the Google drive from a `.ogg` blob created in the browser?

Comment: Do you have to use ``application/vnd.google-apps.audio`` instead of ``audio/ogg`` as a mimeType, when the file is created?

Comment: What is the textual error message?

Comment: I added the error. Unfortunately it is a google translate of this. Exception: mediaData 매개변수는 업로드에 Blob 유형만 지원합니다.

Comment: @Tanaike It doesn't seem to matter which mime type I use - still have the same error.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I posted an answer. ``blob`` is converted to base64 and sent to WebApps. Please think of this as one of several answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about these modifications?

### Modification points :

#### javascript side :

- Encode `blob` to base64, and sent it as the string data.

#### GAS side :

- Decode base64 to `blob`, and save it as a ogg file with the mimeType of `audio/ogg`.
- Save the file as `audio/ogg`.

  - In my environment, it couldn't convert from `audio/ogg` to `application/vnd.google-apps.audio`.

### Modified script : javascript side

#### From :

```
axios.post("https://script.google.com/macros/s/SOME_ID/exec", blob)
  .then((response)=>{
   console.log(response)
  }).catch(error =>{
   console.log(error)
  })
```

#### To :

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
reader.onloadend = function() {
  base64 = reader.result.replace(/^.*,/, "");
  let data = new URLSearchParams();
  data.append('data', base64);
  axios.post(
    "https://script.google.com/macros/s/SOME_ID/exec",
    data,
    {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
  ).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response)
  }).catch(error =>{
    console.log(error)
  });
}
```

### Modified script : GAS side

#### To :

```
function createNewSoundFile(base64){
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(base64.parameters.data); // Added
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data); // Added

  var title = 'Was created from a recording'
  var folderId = 'SOME_FOLDER_ID'
  var resource = {
    title: title,
    parents: [
      {
        "id": folderId, 
//        "kind": "drive#fileLink" // I didn't know whether this is required.
      }
    ],
    mimeType: "audio/ogg", // Modified
  };
  try{

  var newfile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob).id

  } catch(e){
   // Send error to Google sheet
   // Exception: The mediaData parameter only supports blob types for uploads.

  }
}
```

### Note :

- In my environment, `{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}` was required for the script of javascript side. If it is not required in your environment, please remove it.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: You totally nailed it. We have been trying for months to get this working. Your code opens up a whole new avenue for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jason Allshorn Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved. Also I could study from your question. Thank you, too.